# Aggregation - doing a $geoNear AFTER a search mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I want to make a $geoNear operation to the results of a $search operation to list the results in order from nearest to farthest. The order of the operations is important because I first get the items and then $lookup for their location fields in another collection which is required for the geoNear operation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Can you show us what you have tried and provide a sample of your data ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far.